# Detecting "page description retrieval" HTTP requests

Tags: java, http, servlets

I'm building some sort of API which allows user to send us request via GET/POST request, and we always share this URL across email, messaging apps (whatsapp, facebook).

Every time our endpoint is accessed, we'd process with the information provided and "deduct" some sort of "balance" of that user.

Back to the sharing part, the URL we share would include information in GET parameter, example https://www.example.com?do=eat_something&user=somebody&pass=secret, when we share this on Whatsapp, we noticed that Whatsapp would somehow make a call to our system, to retrieve maybe the metadata of our webpage, so it can display nice details of the website on the shared message, problem is that we'd interpret this as a valid request and unintentionally deduct their "balance".

How do we identify if this request is only meant for "page description retrieval"? Is there any general header information we can identify?

Comment: I would try to use the `User-Agent` request header to identify that request comes from WhatsApp, but it can be unreliable.

Comment: @JozefChocholacek Thanks for replying, yep, the main idea is not to stick to "WhatsApp", as there could be many other apps doing similar stuffs.